# How much faster is a low level language than a higher level language?

Tags: python, g-code, cnc

The main two I am considering for my CNC are sending commands through GCODE or Python as the language communicated. I know higher level languages tend to be slower but was wondering how much.

Comment: For a CNC, which language you use shouldn't matter at all, because the CPU shouldn't be the bottleneck.

Comment: ...which is to say, any reasonable language+hardware combination should be able to generate instructions faster than the mill can execute those instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I figured sensor speed should be the limiting factor anyway seeing as it can only read 10 khz a second meanwhile the chip can do 500

Comment: If you're dealing with a smaller microcontroller the above analysis won't always hold, but it's easy and cheap to just put a larger device in place. Hook up a $10 Raspberry Pi that runs Python to generate the GCODE to send to the microcontroller and you have way more CPU than you'll need.

Comment: BTW, if you're curious for some practical numbers about how idiomatic code written in different languages performs, see https://julialang.org/benchmarks/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is too long for a StackOverflow answer.

If you're interested in looking at real world data see this repo:
https://github.com/davepl/Primes

Dave has tests and videos about those tests if you really want to get in to it.